# How to skip the styling of Radio Button Input while using jQuery jqTransform

Tags: jquery, radio-button, jqtransform

Using the jQuery jqTransform plugin, is there a way to skip the styling of Radio Inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the jQuery.jqTransform.js;

The line `if (selfForm.hasClass('ignore') == false) { $('input:radio', this).jqTransRadio(); }` was added to the Radio Button section.

And `class="ignore"` onto `<itemtemplate><asp:RadioButton CssClass="ignore" /></itemtemplate>`.

All working okay now, the transform plugin just ignore's these inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Give the radio buttons that you want to skip: `class="jqTransformHidden"` and jqTransform will skip those.

AFAIK there isn't a way of skipping an element based on its type, only the class.

Comment: When I add the class jqTransformHidden, the RadioButtons actually dissappear altogether

Comment: Are they just hidden? Try showing them after jqTransform is done: `$('input[type=radio]').show()`.

Comment: Yes, they are hidden. However if I add `$('input[type=radio]').show()` they are still hidden. I think what I really need is to exclude them from the styling altogether, like `if class="ignore" Then don't style this alltogether` .. any suggestions?

Comment: AFIAK there isn't an ignore class. Where did you put the .show()? It would need to go after the transform has finished.

Comment: Not to worry, it has been fixed by adding to the jqTransform.js, Thankyou for your help nonetheless.